# Поиск совпадений в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть одномерный массив, заполненный фамилиями (фамилии - string), как найти в этом массиве одинаковые фамилии? Может есть какие-нибудь удобные классы/функции в с#, которыми это можно сделать легко и просто?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко и просто это можно сделать используя [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397926.aspx). Но такой подход не будет самым эффективным.

```
var result = array.Where(str => array.Count(s => s == str) > 1).Distinct();
```

Данная конструкция сначала выбирает из массива все строки, которые встречаются в нём более одного раза, а затем методом [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) избавляется от дубликатов.

**UPD**. Если нужно ещё запомнить число вхождений, то подойдёт такой Linq-запрос:

```
var result = array
             .Select(str => new { Name = str, Count = array.Count(s => s == str)})
             .Where(obj => obj.Count > 1)
             .Distinct()
             .ToDictionary(obj => obj.Name, obj => obj.Count)
```

В результате у Вас будет Dictionary, в элементе которого ключ - это фамилия-дубликат, а значение - число вхождений фамилии в массив.

Comment: а если нужно сначала объявить переменную (я про result), а потом только её заполнять, то какое значение ей присвоить при объявлении?

Comment: Может не так понял, но мне кажется, в таком случае подойдёт null.

Comment: @Comfmore, этот тип - ``IEnumerable<string>``, следовательно подойдёт ``Enumerable.Empty<string>();``

Comment: а если нужно знать сколько раз каждый дубликат встречался? то как тогда сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Я рекомендую не жадничать в отношении строк кода. Лучше жадничать в отношении производительности. Сделаете в лоб, безо всякой функциональщины, но эффективно - и хорошо.

Рекомендую использовать словарь вида Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>. Ключом является фамилия, значением - множество индексов в исходном массиве. Обходите массив, если в словаре уже есть фамилия, добавляете индекс элемента массива в множество индексов по этой фамилии. Если нет - создаёте множество индексов и добавляете его в словарь.

Если требуется получить только дубликаты, создавайте два словаря. Во второй словарь добавляйте только тогда, когда в первый словарь фамилия уже была добавлена.

Comment: ок, возьму на заметку))

Answer (score 3):

Надеюсь такое подойдет :

```
var enumerable = arr.Where(x => x.Equals("Фамилия"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос — вы хотите получить список уникальных фамилий, и для каждой из них знать где она встречается в массиве. Для этого удобно использовать [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341740.aspx).

```
        string[] names = new string[] { "o", "a", "o" };
        var groups = names.Select((name, Index) => new {name, Index}).GroupBy(a => a.name);
```

---

Если непонятно как работать с результатом — вот пример вывода на консоль.

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key + " indexes:");
    foreach (var man in group)
        Console.WriteLine(man.index);
 }
```

Если непонятно как происходит группировка:

1. Для начала массив фамилий преобразуем в массив (на самом деле IEnumerable) пар: {фамилия, индек}. За это отвечает «`Select((name, Index) => new {name, Index})`».
2. После чего просто вызываем `GroupBy` с указанием группировать по фамилии «`GroupBy(a => a.Name)`».

Comment: у Select`a можно выбирать сразу 2 параметра, чтоб не мучать инкрементом локальную переменную:

``names.Select((Name,index)=>new { Name, index})...``

Comment: к сожелению первый раз вижу и GroupBy и Linq(это я имею ввиду предыдущие ответы)
поэтому нужно еще всё об этом читать и смотреть как что работает, т.к. тут такой непривычный синтаксис, что меня это в ступор поставило  )) но за ответ спасибо

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо. Подправил.