# Как посчитать количество уникальных строк в массиве?

Tags: массивы, c#

Есть код из этого вопроса [Поиск совпадений в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83903/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)) - показывает индексы для каждого элемента массива.

*А как сделать, чтобы подсчитывал и выводил кол-во вхождений?*

```
string[] names = new string[] { "o", "a", "o" };
var groups = names.Select((name, Index) => new {name, Index}).GroupBy(a => a.name);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key + " indexes:");
        foreach (var man in group)
            Console.WriteLine(man.index);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
   var groups = names.Select((Name, Index) => new { Name, Index }).
            GroupBy(p => p.Name).
            Select(s => new 
            { 
                Name = s.Key, // Имя вхождения.
                Count = s.Count(), // Кол-во данного вхождения.
                Indexes = s.Select(ss => ss.Index).
                             ToList(), // Все индексы вхождения (в виде списка).

                IndexesCount = s.Select(ss => ss.Index).
                                  Count() // Кол-во идексов вхождения.
            });
```

В итоге для Вашего массива имеем результат:

```
Name  = "o";
Count  = 2;
Indexes = (0; 2);
IndexesCount = 2

Name = "a"; Count = 1; Indexes = (1); IndexesCount = 1
```

**Обновление**

В смысле как? Итерируйте по groups, обращайтесь к нужным свойствам получайте нужную информацию. Делайте дальше с ней (информацией) что хотите.

```
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            string name = group.Name;
            int count = group.Count;
            List<int> indexes = group.Indexes;
            int indexesCount = group.IndexesCount;

            Console.WriteLine(name);

          // и т.д.
        }
```

> Name, Count, Indexes, IndexesCount  - это свойства анонимного объекта, полученного в результате LINQ запроса.

Comment: что-то не пойму, как это в консоль показать. 

Name, Count, Indexes, IndexesCount - это что? Пару слов по теории добавьте.

Comment: Обновил ответ.